# MUI column pinn, different header and cell width

Tags: material-ui, datagrid

I am working with Data Grid from Material UI. I am able to succesfully pin the column, however, with overload of data from other columns, the header and the cell width of the pinned column are a little bit different. When some columns are hidden, the sizing is correct.

I only happens when they are pinned to the right, which I want to achieve.
Changing the alignment of the content in the pinned column doesn't help.
[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRWHw.png)

[Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of7tV.png)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code in a code sandbox please? It will be easier to find what is causing the issue. Just from the image I would say this is happening due to the way the distribution of each cell's width. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `minWidth` in column data like this :

```
{
    field: 'user',
    headerName: 'Adviser',
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 200,
    headerAlign: "left",
    align: 'left',
    sortable: false,
    renderCell: (params) => (
        <Grid justifyContent={'flex-start'} alignItems={'center'}>
            <Grid sx={{mb: 0.5}}>
                {params.value?.['first_name']}
                {params.value?.['last_name']}
            </Grid>
            <Grid>
                {lastLogin(params.value?.['last_login'])}
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    ),
},
```